# solving recurrence recurrence

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, recurrence, josephus

Ok, I'm struggling with Knuth's Concrete Mathematics and there are some examples which I do not understand yet.

J(n) = 2*J(n/2) - 1

it's from the first chapter. Specefically it solves The Josephus Problem for those who might be familiar with Concrete Mathematics. There's a solution given but absolutely no explanation.
I tried to solve it with Iteration method. Here's what ive come up with so far

J(n) = (2^k)*J(n/(2^k)) - (2^k - 1)

And I'm stuck here. Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: J(1)=1, J(2)=2*1-1=1, J(4)=2*1-1=1, J(8)=2*1-1=1... There's more to the Josephus problem than this recurrence though.

Comment: There's a fairly lengthy explanation starting on page 8 of this version of the Knuth book, including many different equations and proofs - http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~vsevani/Concrete%20Mathematics%20-%20R.%20Graham,%20D.%20Knuth,%20O.%20Patashnik.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I will recall the Josephus problem first.

We have *n* people gathered in circle. An executioner will process the circle in the following fashion :

1. The executioner starts from person at position i = 1
2. When at position i, he spares i but kills i's following person
3. He performs this until only one person is alive

By quickly looking at this procedure, we can see that every person in an even position will be killed in the first run. When all the "even" are dead, who are the remaining people ? Well it depends on the parity of n.

If n is even (say n = 2i), then the remaining people are 1,3,5,...,2i-1. The remaining problem is a circle of i people instead of n. Let's introduce a mapping map<sub>even</sub> between the position in the "new" circle and the initial position in the circle of n people.

> map<sub>even</sub>(x) = 2.x - 1

This means that the person at position x in the new circle was in position 2.x - 1 in the initial one. If the survivor's position in the new circle is J(i), then the position that someone must occupy to survive in a circle of n = 2.i people is

> map<sub>even</sub>(J(i)) = 2.J(i) - 1

We have the first recursion rule :

> For any integer n :
>   J(2.n) = 2.J(n) - 1

But if n is odd (n = 2.j + 1), then the first run ends up killing all the "evens" and the executioner is at position n. n follower is 1 ... Thus the next to be killed is 1. The survivors are 3,5,..,2j+1 and the executioner proceeds as if we had a circle of j people. The mapping is a bit different from the even case :

> map<sub>odd</sub>(x) = 2.x + 1

3 is the new 1, 5 the new 2, and so on ...

If the survivor's position in the circle of j people is J(j), then the person who wants to survive in a circle of n = 2j+1 must occupy the position J(2j+1) :

> J(2j+1) = map<sub>odd</sub>(J(j)) = 2.J(j) + 1

The second recursion relationship is drawn :

> For any integer n, we have :
>   J(2.n + 1) = 2.J(n) + 1

From now on, we are able to compute J(n) for *ANY* integer n using the 2 recursion relationships. But if we look a bit further, we can make it better ...

As a consequence, for every n = 2<sup>k</sup>, we have J(n) = 1. Ok that's great, but for other numbers ? If you write down the first results (say up to n = 20), you will see that the sequence seems pseudo-periodic :
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 1 3 1 3 5 7 1 3 5   7

Starting from a power of two, it seems that the position increases by 2 at each step until the next power of two, where we start again from 1 ... Since, given an integer n there is a unique integer m(n) such that

> 2<sup>m(n)</sup> ≤ n < 2<sup>m(n)+1</sup>

Let s(n) be the integer such that n = 2<sup>m(n)</sup> + s(n) (I call it "s" for "shift").
The mathematical translation of our observation is that J(n) = 1 + 2.s(n)

Let's prove it using strong induction.
For n = 1, we have J(1) = 1 = 1 + 2.0 = 1 + 2.s(1)
For n = 2, we have J(2) = 1 = 1 + 2.0 = 1 + 2.s(2)

Assuming J(k) = 1 + 2.s(k) for any k such that k ∈ [1,n], let's prove that J(n+1) = 1 + 2.s(n+1).

We have n = 2<sup>m(n+1)</sup> + s(n+1). Obviously, 2<sup>m(n)</sup> is even (except in the trivial case where n = 1), thus the parity of n is carried by s(n).

If s(n+1) is even, then we denote s(n+1) = 2j. We have

> J(n+1) = 2.J((n+1)/2) - 1 = 2.J(2<sup>m(n+1)-1</sup> + j) - 1

Since the statement is true for any k ∈ [1,n], it is true for 1 ≤ k = (n+1)/2 < n and thus :

> J(n+1) = 2.(2j + 1) - 1 = 2.s(n+1) + 1

We can similarly resolve the odd case.
The formula is established for any integer n :

> J(n) = 2.s(n) + 1, with m(n), s(n) ∈ ℕ the unique integers such that
>   2<sup>m(n)</sup> ≤ n < 2<sup>m(n)+1</sup> and s(n) = n - 2<sup>m(n)</sup>
>   In other terms : m(n) = ⌊ln<sub>2</sub>(n)⌋ and s(n) = n - 2<sup>⌊ln<sub>2</sub>(n)⌋</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Start with a few easy examples, make a guess, then use induction to (dis)prove your guess.

Consider n = some power of 2.

J(2^0) = 1 (given)

J(2^1) = 2J(2^0) - 1 = 1

J(2^2) = 2J(2^1) - 1 = 1

Okay, let's guess J(n) = 1 for all n >= 1.

Base case: J(1) = 1, which is true by definition.

Inductive step: assume J(k) = 1 for some arbitrary k.  Then J(2k) = 2J(k) - 1 = 1.

Therefore, by induction, J(n) = 1 for all n (assuming division rounds down to integers).

Comment: You only proved `J(n) = 1` for every n that is a power of 2

Comment: I don't think so, if you accept the closing assumption of division rounding down to integers.  That is, (2n+1)/n = n and 2n/2 = n for integer n.  Hmm, although now you have me thinking I need strong induction: assuming J(i) = 1 for all i <= k.

Comment: I can't see the point of making such an assumption. In the original problem, if you take the position 1 in the circle and the number of victims is odd, you'll end up dead whereas you wanted to survive.

Comment: Doesn't the stronger assumption allow us to prove the induction hypothesis also holds for all i, k < i <= 2k?

Comment: The purpose of induction relationships is to build a sequence starting from a set of base cases. Here the base case is `J(1) = 1`. From that case, you can build `J(2)` using the relationship, then `J(4)` ... `J(2^k)` and so on ... But you did not build the whole sequence and you can't because you need one more induction relationship to construct the sequence over ℕ

Comment: I'm curious.  If I have an induction hypothesis h, and I have h(1), and assuming h(i) for all 1 <= i <= 2^k (for arbitrary k) I can show h(i) for all 1 <= i <= 2^(k+1), then haven't I shown h(i) for all positive naturals i?

Answer (score 0):

`J(n)=2*J(n/2)-1`

`J(n)-1=2*J(n/2)-2`

`J(n)-1=2*(J(n/2)-1)`

`T(n)=2*T(n/2)`, where `T(n)=J(n)-1`

`T(n)=2^log2(n)*T(1)`

`J(n)=2^log2(n)*(J(1)-1)+1`